# Sort a string in the list alphabetacaly

Tags: python, arrays, list, sorting

i have the following list:

```
strs = ["tea","tea","tan","ate","nat","bat"]
```

i want to sort the strings in that list to be like that:

```
strs = ["aet","aet","ant","aet","ant","abt"]
```

how i can do this ?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try like below:

```
>>> [''.join(sorted(s)) for s in strs]
['aet', 'aet', 'ant', 'aet', 'ant', 'abt']

# Or

>>> list(map(''.join, map(sorted, strs)))
['aet', 'aet', 'ant', 'aet', 'ant', 'abt']
```

Comment: Why not a list comprehension?

Comment: the first approach is list comprehension

Comment: No it's not. That's `list` applied to a generator expression/iterator.

Comment: @KellyBundy, Please Write your recommendation

Comment: `[''.join(sorted(s)) for s in strs]`

Comment: @KellyBundy, thanks, Can you explain different your recommendation and the first approach? I don't have any persist, only this solution comes to mind ;)

Comment: Well, they're different things. And the list comprehension is more efficient and pythonic. `list`+generator is just weird.

Comment: @KellyBundy, I check with `dis` and see the different: `import dis; dis.dis("list(''.join(sorted(s)) for s in strs)");dis.dis("[''.join(sorted(s)) for s in strs]")
`. Yes, you're right. First I write the second appraoch `two_map` then convert to the first approach.

Comment: It rather *has* to be different. Imagine you wrote `list = set` beforehand, then your code would create a set instead of a list (the list comprehension wouldn't be effected).

Comment: @KellyBundy, Yes, you're right But we shouldn't do that (We shouldn't use [built-in function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html) as a variable). I think you want to prevent future errors.

Comment: Yes, noone should do that, and I didn't mean it as a reason for using list comp. I just meant to illustrate the difference, i.e., what `list(genexp)` does.

Answer (score 1):

```
out = []
for val in strs:
    out.append("".join(sorted(list(val))))
print(out)
```